# Why doesn't pass-by-refernce work?

Tags: java, reference

I understand that everything is passed by reference in java. But why doesn't it work in this case? I had thought it should print out "Hate" instead of "Love".

```
class Test {
    static class Str {
        public String str;

        public void set(String str) {
            this.str = str;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Str s = new Str();

        String str = "Love";

        s.set(str);
        str = "Hate";

        System.out.println(s.str);
    }
}
```

Comment: References are passed by value, that's why.

Comment: See the discussion on [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835386/java-string-variable-setting-reference-or-value)

Comment: In Java everything is **pass by value**. It just so happens that the "value" of an Object is the reference to its location in the heap.

Comment: [My answer might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9404727/597657).

Comment: "I understand that everything is passed by reference in java." Then you have a basic *mis*-understanding.

Answer (score 1):

in `main` function, `str` just stores the reference to a string. When doing `str = "hate"`, the reference changes but the original object `"love"` has been stored in `s.str` and remains there.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/567555) for more clarification.

Answer (score 1):

With `str = "Hate"`, you have only changed your local `str` reference to "Hate"; `s.str` still refers to "Love", so that's what is printed.

Comment: The fact that "s.str still refers to "Love"", seems to show that it's passed by value, not reference. Only when it's passed by value, it won't affect the value inside the function. So, doesn't the java reference behave the same as the pointer in C++ in passing arguments to a function?

Comment: The Java object reference is more like a C++ pointer than a C++ reference, in that if you change one Java object reference, another Java reference that was initialized with the first reference still refers to the old value.

Comment: So, in Java, if I do: