# Java: String immutability and operator ==

Tags: java, string, immutability

I have this code which I cannot understand. In the beginning you can see two identical Strings, and when I compare them with use of operator `==` it says it is true, same as `equals()` method, but when I create two identical strings during runtime operator == says false. Why is this happening ?

**Does it mean that when I hardcode identical strings they are placed in the same position in the memory** and both references point to it? I found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835386/java-string-variable-setting-reference-or-value), but there were no explicit answer.

```
public class StringTesting {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String string1 = "hello";                   //\
                                                    // } same place in the memory ?
        String string2 = "hello";                   ///

        System.out.println(string1 == string2);     //true
        System.out.println(string1.equals(string2));      //true

        String string3 = "hey";
        String string4 = "he";

        System.out.println(string3 == string4);          //false
        System.out.println(string3.equals(string4));     //false

        string4 += "y";

        System.out.println(string3 == string4);          //false ????
        System.out.println(string3.equals(string4));     //true

        System.out.println(string3 + " " + string4);      //hey hey
    }
}
```

Comment: If you go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java), you will find all your answers.

Comment: Your bold text is exactly whats happening

Comment: @RichardTingle Nice rep. I feel like ruining it though :P.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It's nothing to ruin until it hits 31337. ;-) (Say I, who is way past that. :-P)

Comment: @Sotirios I hadn't even noticed!  Thanks for pointing it out or I would have missed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following compound assignment operator:

```
string4 += "y";
```

performs String concatenation at runtime. Since the value of `string4` is evaluated at runtime only. And String concatenation done at runtime creates a new object.

From [JLS Section 3.10.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) (See towards the end of this section):

> Strings computed by concatenation at run time are newly created and therefore distinct.

However if you perform concatenation of two string literals, it won't create a different objects. So the following code will return `true`:

```
"he" + "y" == "hey";
```

That JLS section contains code segment for various string concatenation example:

```
String hello = "Hello", 
String lo = "lo";

System.out.print((hello == "Hello") + " ");          // true
System.out.print((Other.hello == hello) + " ");      // true
System.out.print((other.Other.hello == hello) + " ");// true
System.out.print((hello == ("Hel" + "lo")) + " ");     // true
System.out.print((hello == ("Hel" + lo)) + " ");       // false
System.out.println(hello == ("Hel" + lo).intern());    // true
```

Comment: Also, with `public static final String he0 = "he"; public static String he1 = "he";`, `he0 + "y" == "hey" && he1 + "y" != "hey"` and this is true even if he0 is moved into a different compilation unit.

Comment: @MikeSamuel. Of course. Thanks for pointing that out. Missed it in my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

`string4 += "y";` creates a new object.

String literals however are placed in the same place in memory as an optimization (this is called [string interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning)).

Answer (score 0):

`string1`, `string2`, and `string3` are all string constants. i.e., they appear as constant pool entries in the `.class` file. In Java, string constants are interned.

`string4` is a new string, created by taking the string constant `"he"` and then appending `"y"`. Therefore, it's not a string constant, and is not interned.

That is why `string3 != string4`.