# How do I change a string in a StringArray? Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s1 = "Hey";
        String s2 = "How are you?";
        String s3 = null;
        String s4 = null;


        String[] s = {s3, s4};
        s3 = s1;
        s2 = s4;

        for(String str : s) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

I Tried this, to give s3 and s4 in array s, the value's of s1 and s2, in another project. Output is null null. I don't understand why it isn't working.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835386/java-string-variable-setting-reference-or-value

Answer (score 4):

`String`s in Java are [immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8798403/851811). There's no way you can change the `String` objects `s3` and `s4` are referencing. When you're doing `s3 = s1` you're making the local variable `s3` reference the same `String` instance as `s1`, but the value the array is holding is still the old value referenced by `s3`.

You could think of the `String` variables like some sort of a *pointer* to a `String` object. You can change *where* is the variable pointing to (which instance it is referencing), but you can't change the referenced object.

You need to add assign new (or alrady existing) `String` instances to the array:

```
s[0]=s1
```

The `s2 = s4` statement would just make the `s2` local variable reference the object already referenced by `s4` (which is a `null` reference).

Answer (score 2):

You must change the value directly from the array:

```
s[0] = s1;
s[1] = s4;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful with order of statements. So change:

```
String[] s = {s3, s4};
s3 = s1;
s2 = s4;
```

to:

```
s3 = s1;
s2 = s4;
String[] s = {s3, s4};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the actual `array` not the reference.

```
s[0]=s1
s[1]=s2
```

Answer (score 0):

make it

```
s[0] = s1; 
s[1] = s4;
```

If you are the array, then the values must be changed from the array.

Answer (score 0):

s3 and s4 are only reference to an Object.
You are changing your local reference not objects itself.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think the problem is the assigment of the values.

Try something like this:

> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
> ```

```
    String s1 = "Hey";
    String s2 = "How are you?";
    String s3 = null;
    String s4 = null;


    String[] s = {s3, s4};
    s[0] = s1;
    s[1] = s2;

    for(String str : s) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Also you need to change this

s2 = s4;

Regards