# Strings as reference types

Tags: java, string, reference-type

I'm new-ish to learning Java, but I'm just beginning to understand value types vs reference types. As I understand it, a String is a reference type. Unlike other reference types, however, I can print a String without it printing some weird combination of letters and numbers. Why is that? Furthermore, say I have the code

```
String s1 = "x";
String s2 = s1;
s1 = "xyz";
System.out.println(s2);
```

it will print "x", and not "xyz", even though I changed the object s2 is referring to. This doesn't happen when I change, say, an Array. Why are Strings special?

Comment: strings are immutable. You didn't change the object `s2` is referring to. You just made `s1` refer to a different string.

Comment: java Strings are immutable, so your reassignment actually causes your variable to point to a new instance of String rather than changing the value of the String

Comment: That isn't really related to immutability, that is just how assigning a different object to a variable works in Java.

Comment: @Calaf The accepted and other highest upvoted answers to that question are of dubious value and not correct. I'm not sure if it is helpful to suggest as a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

> Unlike other reference types, however, I can print a String without it printing some weird combination of letters and numbers. Why is that?

Because String, as many other types, overrides `Object.toString()`, and returns another string than what the default implementation returns (it returns itself, of course).

> This doesn't happen when I change, say, an Array.

You're confusing "assigning a new value to a variable", with "changing the state of an object". If you do the same thing as what you're doing here with an array, you'll have the same behavior:

```
char[] s1 = new char[] {'x'};
char[] s2 = s1;
s1 = new char[] {'x', 'y', 'z'};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s2));
```

When you assign a different array to `s1`, that doesn't change what the variable `s2` points to.

Of course, if s1 and s2 points to the same array, and you modify that array, then they both keep pointing to the same, modified array:

```
char[] s1 = new char[] {'x'};
char[] s2 = s1;
s1[0] = 'y';
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the implementation of `Object#toString`:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Now, this is the implementation of `String#toString`:

```
public String toString() {
    return this;
}
```

Calling `System.out.println(String s)` prints directly the inner char array representation, whereas `System.out.println(Object o)` is implemented like this:

```
public void println(Object x) {
    String s = String.valueOf(x);
    synchronized (this) {
        print(s);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

And lastly, the implementation of `String#valueOf`:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

Due to this, calling `System.out.println` on an object that did not override the `toString` method results in calling `Object#toString`, which returns the name of the class appended by hashCode.

Concerning your second question, see [Java String variable setting - reference or value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5835386/5362510)